# Is there a way to directly pull a CSV file from this URL? Having problems writing a script to pull files daily

Tags: python, html, csv, web

I am currently trying to write a script that pulls a CSV file from the Acquisition Planning Forecast System (APFS) [website](https://apfs.dhs.gov/forecast/) daily, but unfortunately the HTML button group that points to the file is contained all under one URL and cannot be differentiated from the other files (https://apfs.dhs.gov/forecast/#). I am trying to use Python request in order to download it and then am using a CSV to SQL filter to put it into a database, but I cannot even pull it from the website at this point. Has anyone had any problems similar to this or does anyone have a solution to pulling just the CSV file from the URL using Python request or another access?

If Python request won't work, do you think it would be a decent idea to run a daily script that uses the mouse and keyboard inputs to download the file?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open Firefox or Chrome developer tools and click on the link, you will see the URL that's used to download this CSV.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://apfs.dhs.gov/forecast/?action=csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     APFS Number                                        Description Contract Status     Component  ...  Anticipated Award Quarter          POC Name           POC Phone                       POC Email
0    F2014024399  CG-C4IT SC has a requirement and intends to aw...             REC   USCG/CG-914  ...                    Q2 2025          Joe Chop        757-686-4235          joseph.a.chop@uscg.mil
1    F2014024733  Overhaul of Hamilton Sundstrand 54H60-117 Prop...             NEW      USCG/ALC  ...                    Q1 2021    Andrea Gardner        252-335-6407       Andrea.C.Gardner@uscg.mil
2    F2015026262  In accordance with the National Flood Insuranc...             NEW          FEMA  ...                    Q4 2020     Barry  Taylor        202-646-3023       Barry.Taylor@fema.dhs.gov
3    F2015028763  This contract provides information technology ...             REC   USCG/CG-914  ...                    Q4 2021       Susan Miles      (757) 628-4030          susan.c.miles@uscg.mil
4    F2016031320  The contractor shall provide Cybersecurity Ser...             REC   USCG/CG-914  ...                    Q4 2020    Matthew Wendel      (703) 313-5619       matthew.a.wendel@uscg.mil
..           ...                                                ...             ...           ...  ...                        ...               ...                 ...                             ...
733  F2020051130              Mesosphere Enterprise DC/OS Lic Maint             REC  CBP/OIT/EDME  ...                    Q4 2020  Christina Matias        571-468-0260  Christina.J.Matias@cbp.dhs.gov
734  F2020051142  2011-9757 - Wickr Software and Professional Se...             NEW       CBP/OIT  ...                    Q4 2020    Joshua  Powell        202-644-2598     JOSHUA.J.POWELL@cbp.dhs.gov
735  F2020051174  This acquisition is to renew an annual subscri...             REC         USCIS  ...                    Q4 2020     David  Dahler      (202) 480-3090      david.dahler@uscis.dhs.gov
736  F2020051189  A base plus 4 option years bid for Kenneling s...             NEW       CBP/OFO  ...                    Q4 2020    Shawn Couthren  360-332-6429 ext 4    Shawn.L.Couthren@cbp.dhs.gov
737  F2020051194        to procure MacBook pro laptops for the NCFI             NEW          USSS  ...                    Q4 2020       Pamela Ante          2024077000        PAMELA.ANTE@usss.dhs.gov

[738 rows x 16 columns]
```